# Display the month and how many were hired in that month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to list how many were hired in each month. I'm not sure where I went wrong but I get 23 rows and get duplicate months.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(E.BusinessEntityID) AS NumberOfEmployees,
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 1 THEN 'Janurary'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 2 THEN 'Feburary'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 3 THEN 'March'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 4 THEN 'April'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 5 THEN 'May'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 6 THEN 'June'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 7 THEN 'July'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 8 THEN 'August'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 9 THEN 'September'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 10 THEN 'October'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 11 THEN 'November'
    WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,E.HireDate) = 12 THEN 'December'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS Month
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS E
GROUP BY
E.HireDate;
```

Comment: Let's ignore the select list. Grouping by HireDate means you get one row for each unique hiredate value. That surely is not what you want. Without knowing what you want as a result, it is difficult to provide an alternative. Either pivot if you want one column per month or simply count and group by month(HireDate). The twist you need to consider - what do you desire if hiredate spans more than a single year?

Comment: I was not given instructions if it spans more than a year. Rather they just want the total of hires per month. So one column per month is what I'm looking to do and I thought I was going in the right direction but my results say otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `DATENAME` function for month name and `group by`  for month-wise count

```
    SELECT COUNT(E.BusinessEntityID) AS NumberOfEmployees,
    DATENAME(mm,E.HireDate) from t
    group by DATENAME(mm,E.HireDate)
```

But I'm not sure you need `year` or not ,cause if you need year then it will also come to selection and group by

Comment: They didn't specify whether they would want it separated by year just that they wanted a total for each month. It would make more sense for by year but this is how they wanted it.

Comment: March 2017 is a different month than March 2018

Comment: I guess they are _business people_, I would really ask this question, often you'll need to understand not what they say, but what they mean :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to_char(e.HireDate, month) as hire_month

Answer (score 0):

select count(e.businessentityid) empcount, to_char(e.HireDate,'Month') monthname from employee e  group by to_char(e.HireDate,'Month') 
  order by to_date( monthname, 'Month' )